# What are the eigenvalues of $f$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $f$ be an endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$ represented by the matrix:
>
> $$ A =\begin{pmatrix}
> -3 & 5 & -52 \\
> 2 & -2 & 28 \\
> 0 & -1 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> 1. Determine the eigenvalue of $A$.

$ \det(A - \lambda I_3) = \begin{vmatrix}
-3 - \lambda & 5 & -52 \\
2 & -2- \lambda & 28 \\
0 & -1 & 5- \lambda \end{vmatrix} $

When I compute this determinant I get a long polynomial which I can't determine the roots.

$P_A (\lambda)= -(3 + \lambda)(-(2 + \lambda)(5 - \lambda) + 28) - 10(5 - \lambda) + 104$

Is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: What polynomial do you get?

Comment: how about if you tell us the polynomial

Comment: If you didn't make an error, you should have found that the characteristic polynomial has no constant term, which basically reduces everything to the 2x2 case.

Comment: Indeed, unusually clear characteristic polynomial. Matter of patience and catching your own errors.....

Comment: @saulspatz See my edit please.

Comment: Multiply it out.  It isn't really very much work.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah! I see, I only use row operation and never thought about columns. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix is non-invertible: nine times the first column minus five times the second column is the third column. Hence $0$ is an eigenvalue, and the characteristic polynomial factors as $\lambda q(x)$ where $q$  is quadratic.

---

Alternatively, the rational roots theorem will quickly tell you about how to find that the other eigenvalues are $\pm 1$.